# How can I call GetEnumName with a generic enumerated type?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a Generic class which uses an Enum Generic Type. My problem how do I use GetEnumName on an instance of that type?

I've created a small demo class to illustrate the problem:

```
type
  TEnumSettings<TKey: record > = class
    private
      Key: TKey;
    public
      constructor Create(aKey: TKey);
      function ToString: string; override;
    end;

uses
  TypInfo;


{ TEnumSettings<TKey> }

constructor TEnumSettings<TKey>.Create(aKey: TKey);
begin
  if PTypeInfo(System.TypeInfo(TKey)).Kind <> tkEnumeration then
    Exception.Create(string(PTypeInfo(System.TypeInfo(TKey)).Name) + ' is not an Enumeration');
  Key := aKey;
end;

function TEnumSettings<TKey>.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := GetEnumName(System.TypeInfo(TKey), Integer(Key)) <== HERE I get a compile error: Invalid type cast
end;
```

I'm using Delphi XE. So can this be done? And if so how?

Comment: Regarding your edit, I'd suggest that in production code it would be cleaner to add some static class methods like `ToOrdinal`, `FromOrdinal` from my answer. They will allow you to write your `ToString` method as `Result := GetEnumName(System.TypeInfo(TKey), ToOrdinal(Key));` and so avoid polluting this higher level method with local variables and gnarly calls to `Move`.

Comment: I don't think that you *should use the Move command*. The intended way would be using `TValue` related code, like e.g. `TValue.From<TKey>(Key).AsInteger`, I'd say.

Comment: @TLama That results in `EInvalidCast`

Comment: @David, so is that broken, or did I get the `TValue` casting wrong ?

Comment: I think it is broken, because I get the same error here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan regarding your suggestions of static metods you have a point. but this small class where just create for this question.

Comment: @TLama No, you can do it with `TValue`. Use `AsOrdinal`. I added that to the answer.

Comment: Actually simply `Result := TValue.From<TKey>(Key).ToString;` works well.

Comment: Hi Jens instead of editing solutions into your question, you might make up an own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I would do this with a call to `Move`. I have the following type:

```
type
  TEnumeration<T: record> = class
  strict private
    class function TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; inline; static;
    class function TypeData: PTypeData; inline; static;
  public
    class function IsEnumeration: Boolean; static;
    class function ToOrdinal(Enum: T): Integer; inline; static;
    class function FromOrdinal(Value: Integer): T; inline; static;
    class function MinValue: Integer; inline; static;
    class function MaxValue: Integer; inline; static;
    class function InRange(Value: Integer): Boolean; inline; static;
    class function EnsureRange(Value: Integer): Integer; inline; static;
  end;

{ TEnumeration<T> }

class function TEnumeration<T>.TypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Result := System.TypeInfo(T);
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.TypeData: PTypeData;
begin
  Result := TypInfo.GetTypeData(TypeInfo);
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.IsEnumeration: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TypeInfo.Kind=tkEnumeration;
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.ToOrdinal(Enum: T): Integer;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Assert(SizeOf(Enum)<=SizeOf(Result));
  Result := 0; // needed when SizeOf(Enum) < SizeOf(Result)
  Move(Enum, Result, SizeOf(Enum));
  Assert(InRange(Result));
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.FromOrdinal(Value: Integer): T;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Assert(InRange(Value));
  Assert(SizeOf(Result)<=SizeOf(Value));
  Move(Value, Result, SizeOf(Result));
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.MinValue: Integer;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Result := TypeData.MinValue;
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.MaxValue: Integer;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  Result := TypeData.MaxValue;
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.InRange(Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ptd: PTypeData;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  ptd := TypeData;
  Result := Math.InRange(Value, ptd.MinValue, ptd.MaxValue);
end;

class function TEnumeration<T>.EnsureRange(Value: Integer): Integer;
var
  ptd: PTypeData;
begin
  Assert(IsEnumeration);
  ptd := TypeData;
  Result := Math.EnsureRange(Value, ptd.MinValue, ptd.MaxValue);
end;
```

The `ToOrdinal` method does what you need, and I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it to your class.

If you don't like using `Move` in this way, then you can use `TValue`.

```
TValue.From<TKey>(Key).AsOrdinal
```

And @TLama points out that you can avoid calling `GetEnumName` at all by using

```
TValue.From<TKey>(Key).ToString
```

On the face of it, using `TValue` seems to be more in keeping with the ethos of generics and RTTI. A call to `Move` relies on the specific implementation details of enumerated types. However, it's quite interesting to step through the debugger and observe quite how much code is involved in executing `TValue.From<TKey>(Key).AsOrdinal`. That alone is enough to make me hesitate to recommend using `TValue`.

Yet another way to achieve this is to use [`TRttiEnumerationType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiEnumerationType):

```
TRttiEnumerationType.GetName<TKey>(Key)
```

The implementation of this is much more efficient than using `TValue.ToString`, being little more than a call to `GetEnumName`.

Comment: your version with move is not compatible with big-endian systems

Comment: Delphi is always little endian

Comment: Ok, i thought mobile devices are BE. Apparently they can both.

Comment: ARM is bi-endian and Emba operate in little endian mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is an updated version af my class, with the change suggested. Thanks to David and TLama

```
uses
  TypInfo, Rtti;

type
  TEnumSettings<TKey: record> = class
  private
    Key: TKey;
  public
    constructor Create(aKey: TKey);
    function ToString: string; override;
  end;


{ TEnumSettings<TKey> }

constructor TEnumSettings<TKey>.Create(aKey: TKey);
begin
  if PTypeInfo(System.TypeInfo(TKey)).Kind <> tkEnumeration then
    raise Exception.Create(string(PTypeInfo(System.TypeInfo(TKey)).Name) + ' is not an Enumeration');
  Key := aKey;
end;

function TEnumSettings<TKey>.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := TValue.From<TKey>(Key).ToString;
end;
```

And a little test example :

Copy the code into OnCreate of a From:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TEnumSettings<boolean> .Create(True) do
    try
      Caption := ToString;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You might turn into [`the similar fashion`](http://pastebin.com/SKqNgQG1) your constructur as well ;-)